# Program to convert batch of M4A files to 192kbps

Tags: windows-7, audio, music, media-converter

I'm looking for a freeware program that can convert M4As to different bitrates, specifically 192k, so they're good quality but still small enough to transfer to my phone. I previously asked for a similar program but with much broader requirements, and to no luck, so I'm trying again with the absolute bare minimum that I need.

The program must:

- Be freeware
- Run on Windows 7
- Be able to convert a batch of M4A files to a bitrate of 192kbps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Format Factory to achieve this. You can provide a folder full of files or from multiple folders and it will convert the audio into your specified format effectively.

It can, not only convert to M4A, but it supports almost all the audio formats (13 formats).

**MP3, WMA, APE, FLAC, AAC, MMF, AMR, M4A, M4R, OGG, WAV, WavPack, MP2** are all supported and can be converted from one to other.

You can specify the output bitrate they should be converted to. Supports all the bitrates.

Allows you to specify the output folder you wish the converted files to go into.

Comment: Thanks, after trying a bunch of freeware, this was the one that worked in the end.

Comment: @Hashim Glad it helped :) Could you check my other answer for your question and tell if it is working for you.

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28274/youtube-to-m4a-downloader-converter

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), OS X, Linux, Android
- Is CLI so you can batch
- Can [convert a batch of M4A files to a bitrate of 192kbps](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC), around the lines of (untested) `ffmpeg -i input.m4a -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 192k output.m4a`

Comment: `for %i in (*.m4a) do ffmpeg -i %i -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 192k %~dpn_new.m4a` should do the trick for batching

Comment: I was previously using `youtube-dl` for the same purpose, which utilises ffmpeg to do the converting (post-processing). There was a bug in ffmpeg's skipping over of M4A post-processing files that prevented any post-processing on an M4A file being done, and which I've reported to the youtube-dl team, and I'm currently looking for something else in the meantime until that issue is fixed. Do you know if the problem is likely to be the same if I use ffmpeg directly?

Comment: @Hashim sorry no idea

Comment: @Hashim And with `avconv` (a fork of `ffmpeg`)???

Comment: Franck - No problem, I'll give it a try on its own and see whether it works.

@wb9688 - After trying for hours, I couldn't get `avconv` installed on my system, despite doing everything I did to successfully install `ffmpeg`, so I eventually had to give up on it.

Comment: @Hashim you can download the latest win64 build [here](http://builds.libav.org/windows/release-gpl/libav-11.3-win64.7z) and then un7z it.

Comment: Is that from the libav website? I did that several times, unzipped and moved the entire directory to where I wanted it to be, then pointed the Path environment variable to it. It's the same process I used to get ffmpeg to work, but it didn't work for `avconv` for some reason. I also tried with the nightly builds rather than the main ones, but got the same result.

Comment: I expect it doesn't matter which unzipper you use? I used WinRAR for both `ffmpeg` and `avconv`.

Answer (score 0):

[Pazera Free Audio Extractor](http://www.pazera-software.com/products/audio-extractor/?Lang=English) should be able to do that. Free and portable.

> Extract audio tracks from video files to MP3, AAC, AC3, WMA, OGG, FLAC, M4A, WV, AIFF or WAV. Universal audio converter. AVI to MP3, FLV to MP3, AVI to WAV, FLAC to MP3, Ogg to MP3, SHN to MP3.

[image]